# iphone fetchRequest sub entities?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, fetch

If i fetch data from "parent" and assign it to a fetchresultscontroller, i still have to call

```
[parent.images allObjects]
```

in my cellForRowAtIndexPath to get to the child data.
Is this a normal thing to do or can i get the real data from child right in my fetchedresultscontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call

> [fetchRequest
>   setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:@["children"]]

Before executing your fetch request to include values for "children" key as well. By default, all relationships will be faulted.

Comment: Oke thanks, i am using that line of code now, but when i nslog my fetchedresultscontroller i get this:

this is one line from my output i omitted the rest
images =     (
        0x123ee10 <x-coredata://ACFFBS74-2A1B-4356-B21A-C327CAC45245/Images/p4>

Comment: These are the NSManagedObjects of the relationship "images". Reading attributes (like the attribute the image is stored in) from the images managed objects should show give you the result immediately.